# Can't uninstall ruby gem Vagrant to install Vagrant via RPM

Tags: centos, rpm, vagrant

I can't install or reinstall a vagrant on **CentOS 7**.

First, I've followed a tutorial on how to install a Vagrant on CentOS 7 with **Ruby & Ruby Gem**.

After installation, I've typed inside a terminal a command: `vagrant`

and I received a message telling me that this method of installation is deprecated, I shall go to vagrantup.com and install an .rpm package instead.

I've did that, but now when I call a command `vagrant` I have this message:
**bash: /usr/local/bin/vagrant: No such file or directory**

I've tried to uninstall everything to reinstall it from zero, but no success. I can't find any information about to fix this problem.

Any suggestion please ? Thanks

**==== UPDATED ====**

`whereis vagrant` outputs following:
`vagrant: /usr/bin/vagrant /opt/vagrant/bin/vagrant`

Comment: Try `whereis vagrant`

Comment: @ryekayo - `vagrant: /usr/bin/vagrant /opt/vagrant/bin/vagrant`

Comment: Ok you need to update the init script your using to have it point to `/usr/bin/vagrant`. Right now it's pointed to /usr/local/bin/vagrant

Comment: could you send me more info please ? I am null in this scenario

Comment: What command do you use to start vagrant?

Comment: it's not working yet, but usually it's `vagrant up`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can solve this issue: creating an alias (this is more of a hack) or going to the systemd unit file and modifying it so that it points to the correct location for the binary.

1. Fixing via ~/.bashrc - This is as simple as creating an alias in the bashrc file and using source to reload. This is a quick fix, but I'd recommend the latter.
2. Going to the systemd unit file and updating it - There are plenty of resources online to show you how to create and modify systemd unit files. Take a look at this link [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227017/how-to-change-systemd-service-timeout-value) for an example on modifying systemd unit files.

Comment: Ok, I will try your suggestion and will answer you. thank you

Comment: OK i got it, thank you very much ! I've created a command: 1. `gedit ~/.bashrc` 
2. I've added: `alias vagrant='/usr/bin/vagrant`
3. source `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Cool, if my answer works, would you mind checking it off :-)

Comment: Would be nice also, if you could update your answer with my additional information to solve this problem.

Comment: Ok alias is one way of going about it. But ultimately, I would recommend going to the source and fixing the systemd unit file. I am going to modify my answer a bit to provide more detail on both options