# Does systemd "After=" check if services in it are started without failures before starting the service?

Tags: linux, systemd, systemd-unit

*example:*

`bar.service`:

```
[Unit]
After=foo.service
```

if foo.service isn't started correctly, will bar.service start? and what about if foo.service isn't a dependency of anything and will never start?

Answer (score 1):

You should view `After=x` as meaning:

- Start doing this job after you have finished doing job "x".
- It doesn't instruct anything with respect to the result of doing job "x", it only instructs to wait with this job until job "x" has been performed.

From [`man systemd.unit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Before=):

> Most importantly, for service units start-up is considered completed
> for the purpose of `Before=`/`After=` when all its configured start-up
> commands have been invoked and they either failed or reported start-up
> success. Note that this does includes `ExecStartPost=` (or
> `ExecStopPost=` for the shutdown case).
>
> Note that those settings are independent of and orthogonal to the
> requirement dependencies as configured by `Requires=`, `Wants=`,
> `Requisite=`, or `BindsTo=`. It is a common pattern to include a unit
> name in both the `After=` and `Wants=` options, in which case the unit
> listed will be started before the unit that is configured with these
> options.

So that means:

1. `bar.service` WILL start even if `foo.service` ends with a failed state.
2. If `foo.service` is never activated, then `bar.service` will stay waiting until `foo.service` is activated somehow by other units.
3. `bar.service` will most likely eventually enter a failed state due to unmet dependency.
   The time that is used to wait is controlled by other settings like `JobTimeoutSec=`, `JobRunningTimeoutSec=`. (See: [How to change systemd service timeout value?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227017/how-to-change-systemd-service-timeout-value#276785))
   You could use `JobTimeoutAction=` to catch this case.

- **EDIT:** Scrapped (2) and (3) because those only apply if `Requisite=foo.service`, thanks for correcting me @TooTea

Comment: Point #2 is incorrect. Before/After is just an ordering relation, not a dependency. The ordering only matters if both units involved are being started/stopped together (in a single transaction), so After=foo.service simply does nothing if foo.service is never started. That's why you typically combine After with Requires(Wants); the latter triggers an activation of the unit you depend on, and After then takes care of the relative ordering of these two units.